# How to import shapefiles into greenplum with postgis extension?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, greenplum

I know that it could be done programatically,  but is there any tool that I can use directly?   For instance I could import shapefile to postgresql through **postgis shapefile loader**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shp2pgsql` [tool](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg) is the only thing I'm aware of. Are you looking for some sort of UI for this functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,is the shp2pgsql tool avalible in greenplum?